# What is the Active Reports equivalent of Suppress If Blank option in CR?

Tags: activereports

What is the Active Reports equivalent of Suppress If Blank option in CR?

If want to suppress a textbox in ActiveReports if the content is null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write something like the following in the format event of the section containing the control you want to suppress:

this.TextBox1.Visible = (this.TextBox1.Value != null);

Comment: Would not work. I accomplished this in my Stored Procedure itself.